# Is there a quick way to determine the equivalence of two group centralizers?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I came across the question asking, for the group G=S4 and Y = to the centralizer of G being (1234), can you find another centralizer of G being equal to Y? The answer was (4321). I am not so sure how to get this without trial and error?

"Let G = S4. The set CG((1234)) = ?"

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102170/is-there-a-systematic-way-of-finding-the-conjugacy-class-and-or-centralizer-of-a) for a general answer, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130702/find-the-centraliser-of-1234-in-s-4) for another example. Then proceed the same way with $(1234)$.

Comment: The centralizers are equal because $(1,2,3,4)$ is the inverse of $(4,3,2,1)$.